# Cannot populateListView from database using sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

I was trying to populate my listview with data from sqlite in onclicklistener of my load button.

However, something is not working in my code. Here is my code.

```
    public class TotalResults extends ListActivity {

DatabaseManager db = new DatabaseManager(this);
List<PlayerData> contacts;
String name;
int score;
TextView result;
TextView saved;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_total_results);
    result = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.textResult);
    saved = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.textLoad);
    Button save = (Button) findViewById (R.id.buttonSave);
    Button load = (Button) findViewById (R.id.buttonLoad);
    Button delete = (Button) findViewById (R.id.buttonDelete);


     contacts = db.getAllContacts();

     final ArrayAdapter<PlayerData> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<PlayerData>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, contacts);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
      Intent intent = getIntent();
      name = intent.getExtras().getString("name");
      score = intent.getExtras().getInt("score");

      result.setText("Name: "+name+" , Score: "+score );

      save.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            public void onClick(View v) {

                db.addContact(new PlayerData(name,score));
                Log.d("Inserting: ", name);
                Log.d("Inserting: ", Integer.toString(score));

            } 
      });



          load.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

                public void onClick(View v) {


                    //check to ensure there are users

                    if(contacts.size()==0) {
                        String text = "No players stored.";
                        Toast.makeText(TotalResults.this, text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {


                        PlayerData player = contacts.get(0);
                        String showName = player.getName();
                        int showScore = player.getscore();
                        Log.d("Getting:", showName);
                        Log.d("Getting:", Integer.toString(showScore));
                        adapter.add(player);
                        saved.setText("Player Name: "+showName+" Player Score: "+showScore);
                    }
                } 
          });



          delete.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

                public void onClick(View v) {

                    List<PlayerData> contacts = db.getAllContacts();
                    //check to ensure there are users
                    if(contacts.size()==0) {
                        String text = "No players to delete.";
                        Toast.makeText(TotalResults.this, text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        PlayerData player = contacts.get(0);
                        String showName = player.getName();
                        int showScore = player.getscore();
                        Log.d("Deleting:", showName);
                        Log.d("Deleting:", Integer.toString(showScore));
                        db.deleteContact(player);
                    }

                } 
          });




}
```

I already applied the concept of setListAdapter. However,the logcat is supposed I'm getting a name and score from the database but there is no sign of getting data. But the inserted data can be deleted. The load button also doesn't diplay anything on the listview. please help. Thanks in advance.  :)

Comment: hey @Raghunandan i tried to follow your code but there are a lot of methods and functions that I still don't know because I'm still new at Android so I didn't try it. Is there another way of solving it?

Comment: if there is another way someone else will post another solution. But your duplicating your question which is not required.

Comment: @Raghunandan I finally got it to work. But the contents of the listview is not what I expected. It display this **com.example.SimpleGame.PlayerData@44f344eo**. Any ideas why?

Comment: you need to use a custom adapter your contacts is List of type  PlayerData you can also use a cursor adapter

Comment: when i change it cursoradapter, it says the cursoradapter is not generic, it cannot be parameterized.

Comment: get to know more about adapters red the docs. or else you will run into more problems

Comment: ok. going to read now. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

if your data model is sqlite db the most obvious way is to use CursorAdapter or one of its subclasses (for example SimpleCursorAdapter), not ArrayAdapter

Comment: when i change it cursoradapter, it says the cursoradapter is not generic, it cannot be parameterized.

Comment: I tried to use SimpleCursorAdapter but eclipse says i should remove the arguments. :(

Comment: google for: SimpleCursorAdapter tutorial. there are lots of them